# Why is gnome-session and gconfd-2 using 10+% CPU each?

Tags: gnome

gnome-session and gconfd-2 are each using about 10% cpu, with me doing nothing on the desktop. The other day gnome-session got up to 25% (I suspect it was maxing out a single core of the quad core cpu), and I needed to reboot to get it back to normal.

It seems to creep up over a few hours or so. How can I troubleshoot this?

This is on 10.04 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

found the problem of gconfd-2, I am running vncserver and it was starting metacity, stopped that from happening and now its all good.

gnome-sessions is behaving for now.